# Encrypting to PHP's MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 from Python

Tags: php, python, encryption

I'm making a request to a PHP API, which uses

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, __KEY__, json_encode(__VALUE_OBJECT__), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

Meanwhile, to encrypt the text, in Python I have currently:

```
action = json.dumps({'test': 'value'})
action_padded = action + ('\0' * (16 - len(action) % 16))
aes = AES.new(__KEY__, AES.MODE_ECB)
aes.block_size = 256
encrypted = aes.encrypt(action_padded)
```

Now if I try to decrypt it via PHP interactive shell for testing purposes, it fails (so does the actual service call), just prints bunch of jibberish.

Also reading some threads about the mcrypt ECB mode is that it doesn't need padding, but I'm not sure about that. Right now I just do NULL-padding.

Worth mentioning, I do not own the API and I cannot change it. So I have to adapt what PHP uses.

Comment: You are in for some major pain. `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` **is not AES**. It is Rijndael with a 256 bit block size. AES is only specified with a 128 bit block size. You didn't say what python library you are using but I doubt `aes,block_size = 256` does anything.

Comment: That I understood. I decided to dump this idea to use the APIs self-defined encryption and force it to use https. But I was using pycrypto.